# three.js on winform application c#

Tags: three.js, babylonjs

I wonder that can I use three.js or babylonjs on winform application c# or not?
If yes, can I load some values from Datagridview table and draw 3D shapes?

thanks,
Ahmet.

Comment: Do you mean in a `WebBrowser` control?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  If you're asking whether you can use JavaScript code directly in your C# or VB application then the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

No sure about this git project but try it, if is what you looking for https://github.com/delaneyj/three.net this is the webGL own integrated on all major browser by default, or sometime need to be activated for linux os browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CefSharp in your WinForms together with Three.js or Babylon.js.

[How to use CefSharp (chromium embedded framework c#) in a Winforms application](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application)

[image: WinForms and Babylon.js]